# mb_convert_encoding() not working with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, mbstring

For some reason, when running `mb_convert_encoding` in phpunit, I am getting unexpected results. For example doing the following:

`var_dump( mb_convert_encoding( utf8_decode( 'ö' ), 'UTF-8' ) === 'ö' )`

The above returns `bool (true)` under PHP-FPM, and PHP-CLI, however under PHPunit returns false, `mb_convert_encoding()` is doing something, it just encodes to a messed up string.

Comment: Is it possible that phpunit uses different php.ini, where php_mbstring extension is not enabled?

Comment: @mins the `mbstring` extension is loaded, as I said - mb_convert_encoding does return _something_ it;s just wrong!

Comment: Is your `test.php` encoded in UTF-8 without BOM?

Comment: @qeremy how do I encode my test in UTf-8 and what is BOM? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are using a different set of mbstring ini settings. Here is one way to troubleshoot that. First in the cli you can run `php -i |grep -i "mb"` to see them.

Then create a phpunit test that asserts the values are all the same. Here is mine (I only did the likely suspects):

```
class MbStringTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

function test1(){
$this->assertEquals('UTF-8', ini_get('mbstring.internal_encoding'));
$this->assertEquals(0, ini_get('mbstring.encoding_translation'));
$this->assertEquals('', ini_get('mbstring.detect_order'));
$this->assertEquals(0, ini_get('mbstring.strict_detection'));

$s='ö';
$this->assertEquals($s,mb_convert_encoding( utf8_decode( $s ), 'UTF-8' , 'ISO-8859-1'));
}

}
```

**Aside:** I couldn't get your code to work. I needed to tell it the source encoding is ISO-8859-1. I.e. auto-detection of input character set got it wrong. If you're just looking for a quick fix and don't care why, adding that 3rd parameter explicitly to `mb_convert_encoding` may be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer but I think needs to attach image here;

I aim to show that how to change your unicode-containing pages to proper encoding with coding editor. I do it with Notepad++ so, but you need to check your editor encoding options.

[image: Notepad++ encoding options]

Meanwhile, I'd wish to be an expert on computer science but I am not :). It was a just suggestion that how I solve the unicode problems on my side, First I try "Convert to UTF-8", if does not work, then "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM" and this option had every time solved my problem in the past. But if you wonder about BOM, check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: My files are definitely UTF-8 as this is working on both PHP-CLI and PHP-FPM